# Updating MySQL trigger with additional Query and Insertion Logic

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in a MySQL 5.7.28 database.  One table with submitted XML data from a form dumped into a single column called **xmlData**
The second is a table with serves as a datasource for a Datatables based JS site, called **Employees**

When the xml data is first submitted to the **xmlData** table, I use the MySQL trigger below to parse and insert the data into **Employees**.

```
use test;

DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS test.Update_xmlData$$
CREATE TRIGGER test.Update_xmlData AFTER INSERT ON xmlData

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

replace INTO employees (first_name, last_name, startTime, endtime, date)

select ExtractValue(xmlData, '/Data/Employee/first_name') as first_name,
ExtractValue(xmlData, '/Data/Employee/last_name') as last_name,
ExtractValue(xmlData, '/Data/Employee/StartTime') as startTime,
ExtractValue(xmlData, '/Data/Employee/EndTime') as endtime,
ExtractValue(xmlData, '/Data/Employee/date') as date
from xmlData;

END
```

The output of which looks like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
first_name |  last_name   |   startTime   |   endTime   |     Date
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  Luke     |  Skywalker   |   08:00       |    15:00    |  2019-12-05
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Santa    |   Clause     |   08:00       |    14:00    |  2019-12-25
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This trigger works fine and inserts the data properly.  The complication is that there *maybe* multiple start and endtimes in the submitted xmlData row.  One set for each day of the week.
For the time being, I'd like to query the submitted XML and persist these values in the **Employees** table as separate rows.  For example, if there are Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday start/end times
the inserted data would look like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
first_name |  last_name   |   startTime   |   endTime   |     Date
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  Luke     |  Skywalker   |   08:00       |    15:00    |  2019-12-05
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Luke     |  Skywalker   |   09:00       |    17:45    |  2019-12-06
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Luke     |  Skywalker   |   06:00       |    18:00    |  2019-12-07
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Santa    |   Clause     |   08:00       |    15:00    |  2019-12-25
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What would be the best approach for updating the trigger to insert new rows IF there are existing StartTime/EndTime for additional days of the week?  Is 1 trigger even still viable at this point?

In plain English, I was thinking something along the lines of :

```
IF TuesdayStartTime and TuesdayEndTime EXISTS THEN insert into Employees another row retaining the same name field values, increment date by 1 day, 
IF WednesdayStartTime and WednesdayEndTime EXISTS THEN insert into EMployees another row retaining the same name field values and increment date by 2 days
```

Submitted XML that is being queried and inserted into employees table:

XML Sample Source Schwartz 08:00 09:00 11:0018:0020191221051312

Comment: Can you loop over all the elements in the XML data and insert them all?

Comment: What is the unique key of the `employees` table that you're using with `REPLACE INTO`?

Comment: What do you mean by start times for different days of the week? Isn't the day of week determined by the date field? Can you show what the XML looks like?

Comment: Or is the date just the date of Monday?

Comment: Inserting them all isn't necessary at this point and there's ~ 120+ of xml elements.  The unique key is 'id' and it's autogenerated.

Comment: I'm pulling the date field from a "submitted on" date.  To simplify things I'm using the "submitted on date" as the start date.                                                                                   The forms looks something like this:
Week 1
Sunday Start Time  _____              Sunday End Time _______
Monday Start Time _____.             Monday End Time _______
Tuesday Start Time ______            Tuesday End The _________

So on and so forth

Comment: Put the XML in the question.

Comment: If you're using `REPLACE INTO` you need another unique key, so it knows which rows to update.

Comment: If none of the columns you're replacing are unique, it will just insert a new row instead of replacing.

Comment: Inserted XML into question.  So I created a Unique index on the employees table and created a second trigger to run to run and insert a different query for the subsequent dates and that seems to work except I need to increment the date field by +1 day for Mondays, +2 Days for Tuesdays, etc.  I tried set ExtractValue(xmlData, '/Data/Employee/date') as date; I know there's an date add function which looks like DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 2 DAY).  My remaining question would be how to insert that function within the trigger after the ExtractValue Statement...

Comment: What you put in the question is just plain text, not XML. Where are the multiple entries for the same name with different days?

Comment: Anyway, what you need to do is write a loop that increments a variable from 0 to 6. For each value, look for the corresponding day of the week in the XML, and if you find it update the corresponding row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar described I can create a loop.

I also found a less elegant way that works by extracting the submitted date and using multiple triggers for each day of the week:

DATE_ADD(ExtractValue(xmlData, '/Data/Employee/date'), interval 1 Day) as date **for trigger_Monday**

DATE_ADD(ExtractValue(xmlData, '/Data/Employee/date'), interval 2 Day) as date **for trigger_Tuesday**

Creating an Index of type Unique on the Employees table prevents duplicates.